# Import wire methods from gbloal class to specific js LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, getpicklistvalues

Hello everybody I am working on various LWC forms that contains several fields from an specific object. I want to create a global js file where I can put all of the field imports like this one:

```
import item1 from '@salesforce/schema/SObject.S_Item1__c';
```

and I also want to use the getPicklistValues method in this file:

```
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
```

In order to be able to get all of the picklist values from those fields in all of my various LWC forms. By doing this I avoid repeating the same code that allows me to bring all of the picklist values. But the problem I am facing is that in the global js file I created methods for each one of the getPicklistValues fields like this one:

```
getItem1PicklistValues(){
        picklistItem1 = [];
        @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: defaultRecortTypeIdLabel, fieldApiName: item1 })
        wiredPicklistItem1({data,error}){
            if(data){
                this.picklistItem1 =  data.values;
                return this.picklistItem1;
            }
        }
    }
```

So, in this way in my lwc form js file I can instance the global class and bring each picklist value but I am getting the next error:

```
Leading decorators must be attached to a class declaration.
```

In the line:

```
   @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: defaultRecortTypeIdLabel, fieldApiName: item1 })
```

In order to call the getItem1PicklistValues method in each one of my LWC files and use it.

Could anybody help me to solve this? And tell me how to use this class in my other js files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to separate concerns by using various service components.

First, we can export the schema data in a component. Note that there is no `.html` file here, as it is only JavaScript.

```
// c/fields
export { default as item1 } from '@salesforce/schema/SObject.S_Item1__c';
```

Now, we can create a mixin. This allows us to export a class that extends another class.

```
// c/loadPicklistValues
import * as fields from 'c/fields';
import { wire } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

export default (superclass) => class extends superclass {
  @wire(getPicklistValues, { fieldApiName: fields.item1 }) item1PicklistValues;
}
```

Finally, we can use that in our other components:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import picklistValues from 'c/loadPicklistValues';
export default class MyComponent extends picklistValues(LightningElement) {
  // Example usage
  handleClick() {
    console.log(this.item1PicklistValues);
  }
}
```

Note that, as usual, wire data is not available until after the first `renderedCallback` has had a chance to fire, but you can bind to anything in your mixin class in the template, and it will render as you'd expect.